# How to refresh a p:dataTable after closing a dialog in PrimeFaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I need your help in refreshing the whole `dataTable` with pagination once I closed the `dialog`. With the current code after closing the `dialog`, the `dataTable` will be refreshed if the selected item is in the first page and I can see the updates.

However, if I have searched for a particular item using the filter and then I clicked on the view icon to view the dialog and then close the `dialog`. The `dataTable` will not be refreshed unless I deleted the searched item from the filter and then I tried to search for it again, I will find the updates.

The code for the page is:

```
<h:form id="Requests">
    <p:dataTable id="PendingRequests"
                 var="hr"
                 value="#{hrd.pendingRequests}"
                 paginator="true"
                 rows="15"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 filteredValue="#{hrd.filteredPendingRequests}">

        <p:column headerText="Req. No." sortBy="#{hr.reqNo}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{hr.reqNo}">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.reqNo}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Print Count" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{hr.printCount}">
            <h:outputText value="#{hr.printCount}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">View</f:facet>
            <p:commandButton id="submitbutton"
                             update=":Requests:#{hr.dialogueName} "
                             oncomplete="PF('#{hr.certificateDialogue}').show()"
                             title="View">

                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{hr}" target="#{hrd.selectedRequest}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And the code for the `dialog` is:

```
<p:dialog id="employmentCertificateDialog"
          header="Certificate"
          widgetVar="employmentCertificateDialog"
          modal="true"
          showEffect="fade"
          hideEffect="fade"
          resizable="true">

    <p:ajax event="close"
            listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"
            update=":Requests:PendingRequests"/>
</p:dialog>
```

And the `UpdateDatatable()` method has the code:

```
public void UpdateDatatable(CloseEvent event) {

    listPendingRequests = new ArrayList<PendingRequests>();

    try {
        //Select Statement

        while (result.next()) {
            PendingRequests pendingList = new PendingRequests();
            reqNo = result.getString("REQ_SEQ_NO");
            printCount = result.getString("DOC_PRINTED_CNT" + 1);
            pendingList.setReqNo(reqNo);
            pendingList.setPrintCount(printCount);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you seem to be using the filteredValue... do you also update the record in there? Or maybe not actually update the datatable via the update attribute on the ajax tag but give the datatable a `widgetVar="dtWidgetVar"` attribute and do  `onComplete="PF('dtWidgetVar').filter()"` on the ajax tagb

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, I will be filtering for a value and then I will click on the icon view it. If I close the dialog, I need to update that record count to be incremented by 1. I will try your suggestion to keep the onComplete in the ajax tag while closing the dialog and I will see. But, what does the onComplete="PF('dtWidgetVar').filter()" mean?

Comment: @Kukeltje My issue is that I want to refresh the dataTable once I closed the opened dialog

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the help ... it worked

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the widgetvar to the dataTable `widgetVar="dtWidgetVar"`

and then:

```
<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}" update=":Requests:PendingRequests" onComplete="PF('dtWidgetVar').filter()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
<p:dialog id="dialog-test" onHide="refreshTable();">
  ...
</p:dialog>
```

Place at the end of your page:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshTable" action="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"
                 partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="Requests" />
```

If you need send information from your dialog to backBean maybe you need change the process, adding the dialog id or the element id what you want to send:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshTable" action="#{hrd.UpdateDatatable}"
                 partialSubmit="true" process="@this, dialog-test" update="Requests" />
```

Good Luck!